# Remove block using admin Custom Layout Update xml?

Tags: magento2, admin, layout, xml

I want to remove a block on specific CMS pages and categories that can be accessed via the admin - rather than trying to figure out handles that will cover all of the pages I want to modify.

I want to remove the sidebar block on the page, however it will only accept the `<referenceContainer>...` not `<referenceBlock name="sidebar" remove="true"/>`

Any ideas? I'm sure I have done this before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strangely, I encountered the same challenge this week. I assume that this reported issue matches your problem: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2247

This is my solution and it is *terrible*, but it does the trick. Create a new container, move your block(s) into that container, remove the new container.

```
<container name="bin" htmlTag="div" />
<move element="block.to.remove" destination="bin" />
<referenceContainer name="bin" remove="true" />
```

I would definitely like to see this issue fixed - I believe it to be a bug though the M2 devs seem to have dismissed it ('works as intended').

Comment: That is absolutely brilliant. XML doesn't exactly put you in a creative mood for problem solving. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. Happy it was useful!

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to do it is probably something along these lines...

```
<container name="body">
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.leftnav" remove="true" />
</container>
```

Comment: As per the issue linked to in my example, this does not work.

Comment: it was not working for me on 2.1.x, but is working now on 2.2.2, just clear the cache after editing

Comment: it does not work in Magento2.2.4

Comment: This worked in Magento 2.3.0. I removed the RSS link for a specific category.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as of 2.3.x.

Answer (score 1):

It will accept the `referenceBlock` if you wrap it in a `<body>` tag. You also may need to use `display="false"` instead of `remove="true"`. Try this:

```
<body>
  <referenceBlock name="sidebar" remove="true"/>
</body>
```